# Angular - insering external PDF link into iframe

Tags: angular

i need your help please,

im trying to insert `external PDF link` into `<iframe>` with my Angular-App :

```
<embed [src]="downloadurl" style="width: 100%; height: 550px;" />
```

but i got this error :(

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to Sanitize the URL and then use it.

Angular mandates all the URLs to be sanitized before using them.

**How do you sanitize the URL?**

Luckily, Angular has got the `DomSanitizer` service for this.

You will have to add these lines in your `your.component.ts` file.

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 sanitizedURL;

 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.sanitizedURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(IFRAME_URL);
 }
}
```

Notes about Sanitization is mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) in the Angular Docs.